# Experience and Tips how to integrate an Angular 2 Application to a JSF Application

Tags: angular, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to integrate a Angular 2 Application into a JSF 2.0 Application to continous get rid off this ugly JSF.
I found a way how to do it but there are some Problems. 
I'm loading the 5 angular JavaScripts into my JSF Application. I also have a div which I use with the angular Attribute Selector. The Selector is app-root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" app-root=""><div></div></h:panelGroup>
<h:outputScript name="js/angular/inline.bundle.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/angular/polyfills.bundle.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/angular/styles.bundle.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/angular/vendor.bundle.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/angular/main.bundle.js"/>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

This is a Panel who is not rendered on the initial page load. 
You see I have to load the JavaScript in this Panel, but I want to load the JavaScripts at the initial PageLoad, because when I have some more Components I have to include these Files at different Panels. But then I have duplicate loads of these JavaScript files.

I tried to load the JavaScripts at the initial PageLoad but this gives me some JavaScript Errors. These are saying that they can't find app-root. That makes sense, because this div with the app-root is not rendered yet.

Has anybody an advice for me how to solve this Problem or has someone a different idea how to integrate an Angular 2 Application into JSF?

Comment: Its very difficult , almost not possible. If you have an option go for other framework .

Comment: Ok you mean not Angular?

Comment: We had same problem, its very difficult. It is possible but it will be hacky !!

Comment: Use AngularFaces...

Comment: @Skeptor how does the hacky stuff look like, as we will try to do so too. We thought of maybe using an iframe to keep one small angular app as a usecase inside its own content - "wrapped" by the old jsf1 page...

Comment: My code no longer works with newer Angular. It is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3c9jfr . I dynamically initialized components and add in JSF parallell to app-root . If you are desperate, you can check that code to get some idea and fix it . Let me know if you need help